ASP.NET Core OAuth2 implementation using company account
I'm working on implementing OAuth in an ASP.NET Core (.NET 8, Core Empty template) application and I am trying to get a token by log in into the corporate account. In launchSettings.json I set "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:9001", If I run the following code in Program.cs when calling up http://localhost:9001/login:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication("cookie")
.AddCookie("cookie")
.AddOAuth("a", static opt =>
{
    opt.UsePkce = true; 
    opt.SignInScheme = "cookie";
    opt.ClientId = "12345";
    opt.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://<url>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize"; 
    opt.TokenEndpoint = "https://<url>/oauth2/v2.0/token";
    opt.ClientSecret = "secret"; 
    opt.CallbackPath = "/";
    // fill the Scope
    opt.Scope.Clear();
    opt.Scope.Add("openid");
    opt.Scope.Add("offline_access");
    opt.Scope.Add("https://<url>/File.Read");
    opt.Scope.Add("https://<url>/File.Write"); 
    opt.SaveTokens = true;       
});

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.MapGet("/", (
    HttpContext ctx) => {
        ctx.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
        return ctx.User.Claims.Select(x => new{x.Type, x.Value}).ToList();
    });

app.MapGet("/login", () => {return Results.Challenge(
    new AuthenticationProperties(){ RedirectUri = "http://localhost:9001/" },
    authenticationSchemes: new List<string>() {"a"}); });

app.Run();

the page for sign in is opened and I can put my credentials. After it I get the following error message:

OAuth token endpoint failure: invalid_request;Description=AADB2C90084:
Public clients should not send a client_secret when redeeming a
publicly acquired grant.

My questions are:
What could be the cause for this error and how it could be improved?
Is there another way to achieve this requirement?

Based on your error message  AADB2C90084: Public clients should not send a client_secret when redeeming a publicly acquired grant indicates that the application is being treated as a public client, which should not use a client secret.
To resolve this issue, you need to treat your application as a public client and not provide the ClientSecret. This usually involves using the Authorization Code Flow with PKCE (Proof Key for Code Exchange) instead of the Authorization Code Flow that includes a client secret. You could give a try.
